# CKEditor 4.3.1 - Notice: Undefined index: DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: wysiwyg

CKEditor runs on 7.23 on a local osx 10.8.5. Configured as described in readme.txt without CKFinder.

Editing the CKEditor Profile brings the following:

"Notice: Undefined index: DOCUMENT_ROOT in ckeditor_get_document_root_full_path() (line 58 of /Users/ip/Sites/drupal-vzbv_docs_drupal_7/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.lib.inc).

Creating a new article doesn't show the CKEditor

Google couldn't find any suggestion.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your PHP can't see DOCUMENT_ROOT in [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), you have a problem on a level deep lower than your Drupal... Unless it's a bug in ckeditor module, of course, but it does not look like one.

Comment: I work in a minimal drupal environment. CKEditor only appears if an appropriate TextFormat is defined.